# App-store: Is it a good idea to include a youtube video link in the description of an app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, app-store, ipod-touch

Will the viewers be able to click on a link from a description or is this not possible as far as how the app-store works?

I'd like to show the users what the app will look like before they buy it by showing them a video of it on youtube.

Thanks

p.s and no, this is not a marketing question. Only programmers know the answer to this question because we're the ones that are usually writing the description and hooking it all up. I want to know if feasible or not as far as apple is concerned. If you don't like the question, let someone else answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Apple will like the users being taken out of the App Store, especially on the devices. Also, as the description is text only and there is no way to copy&paste text, putting a link will be pointless.
I would rather embed the video on the website referred as the developer website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have clickable links in the app store description. I have seen clickable links in updates notes for an app.

Answer (score 0):

Most Links to YouTube I have seen in the App Store use a url shortener as plain text in the description.